# Mod_rewrite on localhost does not load the page

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to setup `.local` domain and redirect my localhost request to the respective folders. Currently the folder looks like this:

Document root (localhost) = `/home/user/www/`, projects = `/home/user/www/project1/`

I access the projects like `localhost/project1`.

Now I'm trying to set up domains for my localhost. I added `dev.local` in `/etc/hosts` with `127.0.0.1` which works and redirects to localhost. Now I want to access projects like `project1.dev.local` or `project1.local` and expect it to redirect to `localhost/project1`. I placed the `.htaccess` file in the document root and put the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.dev\.local [NC]
RewriteRule (.*).dev.local dev.local/%1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+).local$ localhost/$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you see, I had been trying both options but neither worked.

`.htaccess` is accessed, I get error when I put garbage in the file. I get the same error (Page cannot be accessed) when I try like `project1.local` or `project1.dev.local`.

Yes, I have enabled FollowSymLinks, AllowOverride and restarted Apache server for each change here. I do not see any error log except the page does not load.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such rewriting rules in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), as you attempt, but that is a questionable approach. Here is why:

- Such files are inefficient, they really slow down the http server.
- Such files add complexity, are hard to debug.
- There is no need for this in your setup.

Instead you should read into the feature of "name based virtual hosts" that the apache http server offers: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/

You define one such virtual host for each project in you http server's central configuration. You can assign a name to each of the using the `ServerName` directive and a section of the file system where the resources reside that this specific host is meant to publish using the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directive. This approach also allows for different settings for different projects, which clearly makes sense for development.

See the documentation for more details and directives. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

---

If you still want to use rewriting for this, for example because you have a huge number of such projects nearly identically anyway and want to save the effort of the few lines to define a virtual host for all of them, then you still want to implement those directives in the central configuration of your http server's default host and *not* in a *distributed* configuration file.

That might point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)?\.([^.])+\.dev\.local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%2
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```